# Selecting tags by content in Jsoup and getting nth tag after the given tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have an HTML document I want to scrape data from. The tag of the data has no unique identifier except that it is the 13th `<td>` tag from the `<td>` tag containing the given string.

So, for example, the 10th `<td>` tag in the document contains the word "dog" ( ie `<td>dog</td>`. Also no other `<td>` tag in the document contains identical data.). Given **only** the word "dog", is it possible for me to extract the content inside the 23rd `<td>` tag in the document using Jsoup methods, and if so how?

**Edit:**

```
<td>Cat</td>
   <td align="center">40</td>
   <td align="center">67</td>
   <td align="center">58<br>0</td>
   <td align="center">32</td>
<td>Dog</td>
   <td align="center">0</td>
   <td align="center">0</td>
   <td align="center">58<br>0</td>
   <td align="center">99</td>
<td>Snake</td>
   <td align="center">7</td>
   <td align="center">85</td>
   <td align="center">58<br>0</td>
   <td align="center">13</td>
```

In a document like this, given only the animal's name, I would like to be able to extract the number in the n'th tag from it, let's say 4. So given "Cat" I would like to find 32. Given "Dog", 99. And for snake 13. Assume there are hundreds of animals in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [structural pseudo selectors](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) to target the nth element.

```
doc.select("td:nth-child(23)");
```

Since you are looking for the row with Dog, you could select that row first.

```
Element dogRow = doc.select("tr:has(td:contains(dog))").first();
```

and then select the 23rd child

```
String cellValue = dogRow.select("td:nth-child(23)").first().ownText();
```

or combine them

```
String cellValue = doc
    .select("tr:has(td:contains(dog)) > td:nth-child(23)")
    .first()
    .ownText();
```

---

**Edit**

I reread your question and seems like you want to find Dog within a row and then find the nth sibling.

You could use the `elementSiblingIndex` and `getElementsByIndexEquals` for this:

```
    Element dogRow = doc.select("tr:has(td:contains(dog))").first();

    int dogCellIndex = dogRow
        .select("td:contains(dog)")
        .first()
        .elementSiblingIndex();

    int otherCellIndex = dogCellIndex + 10;

    String cellValue = dogRow
        .getElementsByIndexEquals(otherCellIndex)
        .text();
```